# Change background color of the selected button basing on its state

Tags: android, button, background-color

I saw some posts with a similar question but they still differ from my problem here. I am making painting app in Android Studio and I want to indicate the option which user selected (whether it is move tool, pencil etc.) Here is the picture: 
[image: Screenshot]

So, I want to change the background color of the button when it is selected and revert it back to default color when another button is selected. 
I tried doing it with XML selector but later I saw that there is now "selected" attribute for a regular button. These are regular buttons. What is the easiest way to solve this?

Comment: try switch and case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a class variable for keeping track of the currently selected button, and detect when a new button is selected. You would then perform the action of "selecting" the new button, and "deselecting" the previous one. Example:

```
private Button mSelectedButton;

private void setOnClickListeners() {
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Button clickedButton = (Button) view;

            //in case no button is selected, this will only "select" the clickedButton
            if (mSelectedButton == null) mSelectedButton = clickedButton;

            //previous selected button (should return to original state)
            mSelectedButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.original_state);

            //your new selected button
            clickedButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.selected_state);

            mSelectedButton = clickedButton; //save currently selected button
        }
    };

    yourButton1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    yourButton2.setOnClickListener(listener);
    yourButton3.setOnClickListener(listener);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Lucas this is exactly what I needed. I am surprised that I could not find this anywhere on the internet...

Answer (score 2):

Try this code (button_selector.xml, put it in your drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray"></item>

</selector>
```

XML

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector" />
```

Comment: This would be a great solution if a regular button had android:state_selected condition, which is not the case. But for those who just need to change the color when you click, it will work, but not to stay selected as in my case...